# SPD : Workflow Item Added Item Updated not working

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow, updatelistitems

I have a doc Library with "CountryName" field (DDL), When the file is Uploaded to the Library, I need to copy it in the respsctive Library (exp file1, countryName = CH it will be copied to Library_CH). 
I found that :

if(Created Date=Modified Date) 
//Then its a new item and workflow is called for first time
Else
//Workflow is running for updated event.
 but my Workflow is not working.
[image]

PS : the following workflow is running but just when I edit a properties file (when I upload file for the 1st time and I set metadata, it doesn't work)
[image]
Help please

Comment: Your first condition doesn't make sense.. It should be only if created equals modified and no OR...

Answer (score 0):

Remove those if conditions and set workflow to run only during item created.

Comment: but I need the workflow to run, if it's created or modified, and I already check those choices

Comment: Take one step at a time.. First fix the problem of the workflow not running then add steps conditions one by one.

Comment: I add to my post, the workflow working for edit properties

Comment: you mean :  If (created = Modified And country = CH) Or ((created = Modified And country = USA) )...

Comment: First statement should be if created = modified... Inside that you can add your other conditions like if country = us etc

Comment: if(created = modified) {if (countryname = ch)} ?????? not working too

Comment: I need to run the workflow for new files and updated files